# How do I go about writing a program that asks for a number until zero is introduced?

Tags: python, list, element

How do I go about writing a program that creates a list of integers that asks the user to enter a new number until zero is introduced.

```
for example
    Enter elements for a list, one at a time. Enter 0 to stop.
    element =  9 
    element = 3 
    element = 1
    element = -7
    element = 2
    element = 0
    Finished getting user input.
    The list is:  [9, 3, 1, -7, 2]
```

This is what I have.

```
listA = [9, 3, 1, -7, 2]
while True:
    input = int("some number: ")


    if input == 0
        break
    print("Finished getting user input")
    print("the list is: [9,3,1,-7,2]")
    else:
        listA.append(int(input))
```

Comment: You should try to do something first, and ask for a specific question. Nobody is going to develop a program for you just like that!

Comment: hi and welcome to SO :) One of the best ways to post a question is provide a little bit of code you're working on or a complete reasoning (if you're in between technologies and don't know which one you should chose). Also, i suggest you read our faqs http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and maybe edit a bit your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mylist = []
while True:
    try:
        input = int(raw_input("add a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "please only input integers, input 0 to quit"
        continue
    if input == 0
        break
    else: 
        mylist.append(int(input))
```

after this loop runs you have a list `mylist` which contains all the integers the user input before he input `0`.

Comment: Inbar, this is really not a good thing to do to encourage people to ask you to do their job for them.

Comment: @e-satis i understand your concern. but this is a legitimate conundrum, not everyone knows about raw_input, not everyone knows about loops, or exiting them properly, this is a python beginner with an idea, and i want to encourage that. so maybe 1 out of 100 times its doing someones work for them, but mostly, its helping someone get into the world of programming, which is awesome.

Comment: I think the idea is that you should be able to describe the reasoning involved and allow people to learn by doing, rather than posting a complete solution. You could have accomplished basically the same thing by linking to documentation on `raw_input` and/or how to do loops, and then used prose or pseudocode to explain what needed to be done.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure you are correct, that would probably have been a better approach, i will internalize this and endeavor to guide more than dictate in the future.

Comment: thanks, this was useful. i am a new to python and programming. and i really don't know how to use this site either seeing how i just made it. i was having trouble just trying to post this.

Comment: @neonlights i'm glad i could be of service. and i hope that my dictation didnt confuse you, but instead, helped to guide you down the path of programming. if you have any questions about this particular code, ask it here. if you have other questions, ask them on the main site. if you feel this has answered the question you asked, you can mark it as accepted by pressing the tick mark ("V") on the left.

Answer (score 0):

To review your code:

```
File "temp.py", line 6
    if input == 0
            ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

if statements need a colon at the end.  Fix that, and retry your program.

Try this:

```
if input == 0:
```

Also, if you get a good answer to your question you should check it so that the person who answered you best gets points